# Altium pad error: Collision between track on bottom layer and polyregion on multilayer

Tags: altium

When I tried to connect a trace to a pad on the bottom layer in the Altium project, I get the following error message:

> Clearance constraint between track on bottom layer and polyregion on multilayer`

[image]

Any idea on resolving this? Do I have to create a stack up to the board or change some layer setting?

Comment: Not an Altium user, but somewhere in your project, probably on your thru via, there is a constraint that says no track within X distance. You have run a track closer to the region then X. There should be some method of clicking on the DRC to find the 2 objects names. Then from there you’ll need to figure out how to fix it. Make X smaller, move the track, etc. Additionally, if you are having these boards manufactured, you may want to find out what X is from the manufacturer.

Comment: What does the other end of that track connect to? Are you sure it's in the same net as the pad?

Comment: Yes its in the same net. The issue was in the initial configuration.

Answer (score 1):

By referring to this altium page, the error creeped in because the layer stack was not properly defined.

So, in the Board Region dialog on the Altium UI we have to assign the stack up to the board region.

[Altium Clearance Constraint removal explaination](https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/clearance-constrain-between-polyregion-on-multilayer-and-pad-on-top-layer)

Comment: This doesn't help

Comment: What are the troubleshooting steps you have taken otherwise?

Comment: There was a wrong rule that cause this don't remember though